# robot framework library JSONlibrary import error

Tags: python, json, import, robotframework

I am having issues with importing JSONlibrary and I am not sure where it fails.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\path\to\file.robot' on line 12: Importing test library 'JSONLibrary' failed: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input 'from' (__init__.py, line 1367)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\JSONLibrary\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .JSONLibraryKeywords import JSONLibraryKeywords
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\JSONLibrary\JSONLibraryKeywords.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jsonpath_rw_ext import parse
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\jsonpath_rw_ext\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    __version__ = pbr.version.VersionInfo(
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 467, in version_string
    return self.semantic_version().brief_string()
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 462, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
  File "C:\Users\path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 439, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    import pkg_resources
```

I tried to pip reinstall robotframework-jsonlibrary and pkg_resources, but it still does not work. It seems that some of the code may be in python 2?

Currently using Robot Framework 3.2.2 (Python 3.7.9 on win32) and pip list:

```
appdirs                    1.4.4
certifi                    2020.6.20
chardet                    3.0.4
configparser               5.0.0
coverage                   5.3
decorator                  4.4.2
distlib                    0.3.1
filelock                   3.0.12
idna                       2.10
importlib-metadata         1.7.0
jsonpath-rw                1.4.0
jsonpath-rw-ext            1.2.2
pbr                        5.5.0
pip                        20.1.1
pluggy                     0.13.1
ply                        3.11
py                         1.9.0
requests                   2.24.0
robotframework             3.2.2
robotframework-jsonlibrary 0.3.1
robotframework-requests    0.7.1
setuptools                 50.3.0
six                        1.15.0
tox                        3.0.0
urllib3                    1.25.10
virtualenv                 20.0.31
zipp                       3.1.0
```

Comment: Could you also update question with a more exact python and packages version. `python --version`, `robot --version` and `pip list`. I think that would be helpful.

Comment: Updated with versions listed

Comment: A long shot, maybe you can try update your pip. Stranger things happened before. `pip install --upgrade pip`